# Remove folder including ignored files

Tags: git, git-pull

I have something like this in my file system:

```
myrepo
|-- project-one/
|-- project-two/
|-- project-three/
|   |-- .gitignore
|   |-- src/
|   |-- build/
```

I configured `myrepo/project-three/.gitignore` to ignore the `build` folder.

I need to delete the `project-three` folder.

The problem is that if I do it and push it the other members of my team will see something like this:

```
myrepo
|-- project-one/
|-- project-two/
|-- project-three/
|   |-- build/
```

How can I delete the `project-three` folder in a way that removes the ignored files when other member of the team do a pull?

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't handle folders at all. What it manages are the files in some subdirectories. The subdirectories in the git object database are created on demand, when a file with some path is to be recorded in the git object database. When you delete all (tracked) files from a directory, and the directory becomes empty, it may be deleted by git. Or may not,. if there're some (untracked) files left.

So likely if your team members have their own build/ directories with their private stuff not tracked by git you can't force git to silently remove it.